# Splitting a string into a string array, then splitting again

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

Hey there wonderful people. I am an active Java student for months now, but still sometimes I come across stuff I am yet to understand. Here the goal was to split an email address into three parts: the **address**, the **domain** and the **country code** at the end.

I came up with the code below, but it throws an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error. I understand this is an issue with the second array, but I don't understand the cause, nor I have another idea for this problem.

I would greatly appreciate your help and insight.

```
    String lineOne = "example@gmail.com";
    String[] arrayOne = line.split("@");

    String lineTwo = arrayOne[1];
    String[] arrayTwo = lineTwo.split(".");

    System.out.println(arrayTwo[0]);
    System.out.println(arrayTwo[1]);
```

Comment: check the contents of lineTwo before trying to split, and the contents of arrayTwo before trying to get its elements

Comment: The argument to `split` is a regex. `.` in a regex matches every character. So you're not getting back what you think you are.

Comment: My favorite: `split(Pattern.quote("."))`

Comment: Yuck compared to just escaping the period; when the pattern is trivial, why bother?

Comment: Thank you for your fast inputs. Indeed I forgot about that the dot is regex.